# Replace white color with transparency in a grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a grayscale image and i would like to replace white to be transparency channel. This means that even pixels that are technically gray simply become transparent black pixels. They will be more transparent the closer to white they actually are.

The image is of an outline and I will place it over the original image so it needs to have no white or gray pixels left. Any solution in python will do.

[image: outline]

Comment: Try use it as alpha channel as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the image as grayscale and use it as alpha channel:

```
alpha = cv2.imread('AxkFm.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

For example, given a solid color image, same size as `alpha`:

```
h, w = alpha.shape
img = np.ones([h, w, 4], np.uint8) * (255, 100, 100, 255)
```

Change the last channel like the `alpha` image (or reversed `alpha`):

```
img[:,:,3] = alpha
# img[:,:,3] = np.bitwise_not(alpha)
```

Save as `img` as `.png`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Differing only stylistically from iGian's answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as greyscale
grey = cv2.imread('AxkFm.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Make 4-channel RGBA black background with same height and width
im = np.zeros((*grey.shape,4), dtype=np.uint8)

# Put your alpha channel in, inverted
im[:,:,3] = ~grey

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]

---

Note that I made a 4-channel RGBA image because OpenCV refuses, for some reason, to write a 2-channel Grey+Alpha image. If you want that, you can do it with PIL/Pillow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the image as grayscale
- Convert it to BGRA
- Negate the gray image and put it into the alpha channel
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('gray_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to BGRA
imgA = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)

# negate the gray image and put it into the alpha channel
imgA[:, :, 3] = 255 - img

# save resulting image
cv2.imwrite('gray_image_trasparent.png', imgA)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("RESULT", imgA)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]